# How to properly set state from if statement

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to update state in `useEffect` hook, but I came up with a problem with it. Inside the hook I have `if` statement where I'm setting the data in `opacityBar` variable, and outside the `if` i need to update the state with that variable, but it's not working. This is the code I have:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
   let opacityBar;
   if(filteredData.length > 0) {
      const inc = (name) => filteredData.find((f) => f.name === name) !== undefined;

   opacityBar = coloredBar?.data?.map((bar: any) => ({ ...bar, opacity: inc(bar.name) ? 1 : 0.333 }));
   } else {
      opacityBar = coloredBar?.data?.map((bar: any) => ({ ...bar, opacity: 1 }));
   }

   setColoredBar(opacityBar);
}, [filteredData, coloredBar]);
```

I've also tried to set state like this `setColoredBar({ ...coloredBar, opacityBar });` but this causing an infinite loop. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: the state will only get updated after the useeffect has run, where you are checking the value of  `ColoredBar`. and if you change the value if dependent variable inside `useeffect`, you will enter in to infinite loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be adding coloredBar as a dependency to useEffect because you are setting the same state in it. Doing this will lead to an infinite loop.

You can instead use functional setState like below

```js
React.useEffect(() => {

   setColoredBar(coloredBar => {
         let opacityBar;
         if(filteredData.length > 0) {
            const inc = (name) => filteredData.find((f) => f.name === name) !== undefined;
            opacityBar = coloredBar?.data?.map((bar: any) => ({ ...bar, opacity: inc(bar.name) ? 1 : 0.333 }));
         } else {
            opacityBar = coloredBar?.data?.map((bar: any) => ({ ...bar, opacity: 1 }));
         }
         return opacityBar;
   })

}, [filteredData]);
```

Comment: coloredBar is current state, what do you suggest to do with it? Because writing it this way is not working. const [coloredBar, setColoredBar] = React.useState(barSeries);

Comment: @Milos we are using functional setState and hence the argument to setColorBar is the current state. Please check `setColoredBar(coloredBar => {`

Answer (score 0):

Because you `setColoredBar(opacityBar);` inside the effect, and `coloredBar` is one of the triggers to run the effect, each time you finish the effect you start it again. just add checker to `setColoredBar(opacityBar);`

---

```
opacityBar != coloredBar && setColoredBar(opacityBar);
```

---

or if you don't really need `coloredBar` to be a trigger for re-run the effect, remove it from `[dependencies]` of the effect